# Creating new module as android library. New seeing package R cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-studio, module, android-library

My objective is to create multiple modules for my existing application. So I created a new module --> android library and separated out all the files and folders into the appropriate java and res folder

Now I am seeing that there is no R.java being generated for either the main module or the new module.

How do I resolve this issue?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

There is solution for fix Cannot resolve symbol 'R' in android studio

```
1) Clean your project
2) Build your project 
3) Validate caches / Restart
```

Try this .. Maybe it worked for you .. If still not worked, maybe you can share your directory folder or your code ..